# Higher order differential equations, show that solutions exist without computing $2xy''+y'xy=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Higher order differential equations, show that solutions exist without computing $$2xy''+y'xy=0$$
I know how to solve this equation, but how do we show without computing it?

Comment: Maybe try to rewrite it as a system of first order ODEs?

Comment: Your equation doesn't seem to be well written. you can factor out by $x$.